# Finding the square root in python with the ** operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, exponentiation

I am slightly confused on what the `**` operator means in python

```
import math 
radius = raw_input("Enter your radius")
area_of_circle = radius ** math.pi
print area_of_circle
```

What I am trying to do is figure out what the `**` operator would do. This is for a problem on [Codeacademy](http://www.codeacademy.com), which involves finding the square root. Plese do not give me the answer just suggestions on a syntax to get the square root.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html The "area of circle" should have given you a clue. ... "pi are squared" (say that out loud...)

Comment: `**` is the same as  `to the power of`

Comment: And `x` to the power of `1/2` is... (though are you sure the square root is what you want if you are trying to [calculate the area of a circle](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/circlesrev3.shtml)?)

Comment: Check your source again, the code you pasted here looks wrong.

Comment: yeah, `radius ** math.pi` is definitely not an equation for area of a circle :|

Answer (score 2):

`**` is the exponentiation operator.

Since you only want hints: if you know a number for which raising `x` to the power of that number is the same as taking a square root, then you can compute the square root of `x` using `x ** that_number`.

By the way, you don't need to compute a square root in order to determine the area of a circle from its radius.

Answer (score 0):

you can just run it and you will find that x**y means x to the power of y like 2***3=8

Answer (score 0):

x ** 0.5 = sqrt(x) could be possible?